# Reshape Dataframe from horizontal column to vertical

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any efficient way to reshape a dataframe from:

(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3, TT, YY and ZZ are columns)

```
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3 TT YY ZZ
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 23 24 25
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 23 24 25
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 23 24 25
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 23 24 25
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 23 24 25
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 23 24 25
```

TO:

```
HH JJ KK TT YY ZZ
11 22 33 23 24 25
11 22 33 23 24 25
11 22 33 23 24 25
11 22 33 23 24 25
11 22 33 23 24 25
11 22 33 23 24 25
44 55 66 23 24 25
44 55 66 23 24 25
44 55 66 23 24 25
44 55 66 23 24 25
44 55 66 23 24 25
44 55 66 23 24 25
77 88 99 23 24 25
77 88 99 23 24 25
77 88 99 23 24 25
77 88 99 23 24 25
77 88 99 23 24 25
77 88 99 23 24 25
```

HH, JJ and KK are new columns where I would make a vertical stack of column A, B, C and keeping in horizontal stack TT, YY and ZZ

```
A1 A2 A3 TT YY ZZ 
B1 B2 B3 TT YY ZZ
C1 C2 C3 TT YY ZZ
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Column splitting and concatenation

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
ColSets= [df.columns[i:i+3] for i in np.arange(0,len(df.columns)-3,3)]
LCols = df.columns[-3:]
NewDf = pd.concat([df[ColSet].join(df[LCols]).T.reset_index(drop=True).T for ColSet in ColSets])
NewDf.columns = ['HH', 'JJ', 'KK', 'TT', 'YY', 'ZZ']
```

Out:

```
HH  JJ  KK  TT  YY  ZZ
0   11  22  33  23  24  25
1   11  22  33  23  24  25
2   11  22  33  23  24  25
3   11  22  33  23  24  25
4   11  22  33  23  24  25
5   11  22  33  23  24  25
0   44  55  66  23  24  25
1   44  55  66  23  24  25
2   44  55  66  23  24  25
3   44  55  66  23  24  25
4   44  55  66  23  24  25
5   44  55  66  23  24  25
0   77  88  99  23  24  25
1   77  88  99  23  24  25
2   77  88  99  23  24  25
3   77  88  99  23  24  25
4   77  88  99  23  24  25
5   77  88  99  23  24  25
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit longer than the previous solution :

```
#extract columns ending with numbers
abc = df.filter(regex='\d$')

#sort columns into separate lists
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
cols = sorted(abc.columns,key=itemgetter(0))
filtered_columns = [list(g) for k,g in groupby(cols,key=itemgetter(0))]

#iterate through the dataframe
#and stack them
abc_stack = pd.concat([abc.filter(col)
                       .set_axis(['HH','JJ','KK'],axis='columns')
                       for col in filtered_columns],
                      ignore_index=True)

#filter for columns ending with alphabets
tyz = df.filter(regex= '[A-Z]$')

#get the dataframe to be the same length as abc_stack
tyz_stack = pd.concat([tyz] * len(filtered_columns),ignore_index=True)

#combine both dataframes
res = pd.concat([abc_stack,tyz_stack], axis=1)

res

    HH  JJ  KK  TT  YY  ZZ
0   11  22  33  23  24  25
1   11  22  33  23  24  25
2   11  22  33  23  24  25
3   11  22  33  23  24  25
4   11  22  33  23  24  25
5   11  22  33  23  24  25
6   44  55  66  23  24  25
7   44  55  66  23  24  25
8   44  55  66  23  24  25
9   44  55  66  23  24  25
10  44  55  66  23  24  25
11  44  55  66  23  24  25
12  77  88  99  23  24  25
13  77  88  99  23  24  25
14  77  88  99  23  24  25
15  77  88  99  23  24  25
16  77  88  99  23  24  25
17  77  88  99  23  24  25
```

**UPDATE** : 2021-01-08

The reshaping process could be abstracted by using the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

The data you shared has patterns (some columns ends with `1`, others with `2`, and some end with `3`), we can use these patterns to reshape the data;

```
# install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor 

    (df.pivot_longer(names_to=("HH", "JJ", "KK"),
                     names_pattern=("1$", "2$", "3$"),
                     index=("TT", "YY", "ZZ")
                     )
       .sort_index(axis="columns"))
```

Basically, what it does is look for columns that end with `1`, aggregates them into one column ("TT") and does the same for `2` and `3`.